# Reading millions of small csv files as database or a few huge files

Tags: php, mysql, csv

i have a problem with the best way to structure a huge load of price tables.

There are around 50 Products with different options/attributes that determin the price that needs to be loaded in php.

For example:

```
Product 1
Options:
Quantity: 1, 50, 100, 250, ... 300.000
Color: Green, Blue, Red
Size: S, M, L
Material: Wood, Cotton, Stone
Thickness: 10mm, 15mm, 20mm

Product 2
Options:
Quantity: 1, 25, 50, 200 ... 350.000
Color: Green, Blue, Red
Width: 20cm, 50cm, 90cm
Height: 10cm, 30cm, 20cm
```

Some of the product options are different, some are the same for every product (like quantity). One Option can have up to a hundred different values to choose from.

The pricing tables get calculated inside an excel sheet and exportet as csv files.

My approach was to take the id's of my value and generate combination ids like so:

```
Green+M+Wood+10mm = 2341+2342+4532+2346 = 2341234245322346
```

and put them into one big index as a mysql table.

```
price_tables
------------
combination_id    |  product_id   |  filename
------------------------------------
2341234245322346  |  23           |  price_23_2341234245322346.csv
2342234245322346  |  23           |  price_23_2341234245322346.csv
2342234245322347  |  24           |  price_24_2342234245322347.csv
```

And then have my csv files structured like this

```
price_23_2341234245322346.csv
------------------------------
quantity  |  price
-----------------------
1         |  321,22€  
50        |  512,32€  
100       |  1203,54€
```

Or would it be better/faster to read just one huge csv file for every product.
Like this:

```
product_23.csv
--------------------------------
quantity  |  color  |  size  | ... |  price
------------------------------------------
50        |  Green  |   S    | ... |  321,22€  
50        |  Green  |   M    | ... |  512,32€  
50        |  Red    |   S    | ... |  1203,54€  
...
```

Can someone help me how to manage this huge load of data?

Greetings

TrytoFly

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not using a database? This reads like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me...

Comment: every time there is a price change, all the csv files need to be completly new generated, wouldn't this be a nightmare to recreate and fill thousands of mysql tables compared to just throwing my csv files into a folder?

Comment: If it's in a database, you wouldn't need the CSV files at all.

Comment: Agree with @CD001 on this. You need to stop using CSV files for something like this and get everything moved into a database. Your life will be a **lot** easier and simpler if you do.

Comment: Okay, but why is this the case here? I never need to update, delete, change single tables or rows and the tables get generated via vba in some excelsheet anyways, what is the advantage of a (for instance) mysql database here?

Comment: Checking if i got it: from the product files, CSV files are created which list the price for any and all combinations of options for each product?  And that is what you need to read from?  So you want some kind of index of these CSV files?

Comment: Basically yes, or what would be the best way/alternative to achive this.